# How can I tell if a Windows XP install is home or professional?

Tags: windows-xp, windows-edition

I have a non-booting system with Windows XP, I have access to the system partition (by booting with Ubuntu, or even by mounting the HDD in a working Windows machine).

How can I tell, by analyzing the system partition, if the installed SKU of Windows XP is home or professional?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to the Windows\System32 folder, and look for EULA.txt. Scroll to the last line, and it will tell you what media and what version was originally installed

Comment: "I have a non-booting system ..."

Comment: I read that after... So I edited my respone

Answer (score 1):

Use a tool such as [Magical Jelly Bean KeyFinder](http://www.magicaljellybean.com/keyfinder/) to load the registry from the disk while connected to another windows PC.  Use the `Tools --> Load Hive...` function to switch to the external disk.

Comment: It doesn't work... it says "Microsoft Windows XP Service Pack 3 / Product Part No.: A22-00001 / Installed from 'OEM' media" followed by the product key. No mention of Home or Professional...

Comment: Hmm, odd - could've sworn it also showed the edition for XP (it certainly does for Vista / 7) ... Apologies for the red-herring :(